# Visual Studio 2010 - Any way to take a user control (.ascx file) and compile to DLL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

We have several user controls in VS 2010 in a web project that we'd like to compile down to a DLL to use externally. I've seen articles about how to do this in VS 2008 with the publish settings but VS 2010 doesn't have equivalent publish settings and it seems like nobody has a good writeup on how to compile user controls into a DLL and include that in an external project.

Anyone done this for VS 2010? We have both markup in the ascx file and code logic that needs to be compiled into a DLL.

Comment: How complex are your user controls? It might be worth the time to refactor them into custom web controls, so they can be easily shared.

Comment: Fairly complex -- so there's no good way in 2010 for this equivalent to the ease of 2005/2008 according to MSDN's article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479318.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://devio.wordpress.com/2011/02/11/migration-asp-net-user-controls-to-a-dll-in-visual-studio-2010/

Comment: No cleaner way? Compared to an MSDN article for 2005, this seems much more hackish.

Comment: Acording to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2005/10/31/turning-an-ascx-user-control-into-a-redistributable-custom-control.aspx this still work in 2010

Comment: I just got it to work -- my project was a web application project and needed to be a web site project to see those extra options -- the blog linked above worked perfectly after that. Thanks!